# Trouble accessing an array passed through execlp

Tags: c, arrays, fork, exec, argv

I am having trouble with passing an array though exec. I can only ever seem to get the first element after passing it. I know the pointer only points to the head, but the rest should be in contiguous memory.

```
//runner
int nums[10];
int* nums1=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
nums1=nums;//I know it's redundant
...
execlp("mean","mean",nums1,(char *)NULL);

//Mean.c main
int nums[10];
*nums=argv[1][0];
```

The rest of the program sums, in a for loop, the values of nums, and divides by 10 for the mean.

This is giving me the first element correctly in mean, and the rest garbage when I try to run through the numbers. I have tried everything I can think of(*nums+i, nums[i]) and can't figure out what's causing the error. The runner nums is populated correctly, but no matter how I try to access the array after passing, I'm only given what I've determined is argv[1][i], and everything past i=0 is undefined. I.e.

```
10 0 4196061 0 0 0 0 0 4195984 0
```

versus

```
10 3 5 6 33 23 2 3 3 4
```

Comment: Your `//I know it's redundant` line is actually *worse* than redundant. It leaks memory, because you didn't `free` what you `malloc`'d earlier! Also, I do not understand why you are defining `nums1` at all when you are clearly just using it as an extra name for `nums`.

Comment: `execlp` is a function with variable arguments, also called ellipse. You cannot expand an array into the multiple arguments of an ellipse. If you want to have the parameters in an array and you want to pass the array as a whole, then you have to use `execvp` instead. Note that the 0-th element of the array is what is passed as `argv[0]` (in most cases the same as the path) and the last element of the array *must* be NULL.

Comment: Also the arguments shall be C strings! Just because you don't get a compiler warning (due to the variadic function) does not mean your code is correct. Read the man-page of the functions you use! Maybe you first want to learn the basics correctly before fiddling with processes, etc.

Comment: @Pablo: Please stay nice.

Comment: @alk: I don't see where I wasn't "nice", I just pointed out that crappy code was crap. Maybe I shouldn't have used the word crap, I admit that.

Answer (score 0):

As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774918/olaf) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800990/trouble-accessing-an-array-passed-through-execlp#comment66894865_39800990), you can only pass an array of strings to another program.

Further, with [`execlp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execlp.html), the size of the array must be known when the launching program is compiled; the number of arguments that can be passed with `execlp()` is fixed.  If you want to pass an unknown or variable number of arguments, you must use `execvp()` instead.  That requires a null-terminated array of pointers to strings.

In context, that might mean:

```
int num_values = 10;
int nums[10] = { …appropriate initialization… };

char **argv = malloc((num_values + 2) * sizeof(*argv));
if (argv != 0)
    …report error…abandon ship…

argv[0] = "means";
for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++)
{
    argv[i+1] = malloc(20);   // Big enough for 64-bit signed integer
    if (argv[i+1] == 0)
        …report error…maybe free memory…abandon ship…
    snprintf(argv[i+1], 20, "%d", nums[i]);
}
argv[num_values+1] = NULL;
execvp(argv[0], argv);
…report error…abandon ship…
```

The 'abandon ship' process is probably an `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or similar operation — typically, you've forked a child process to run the other program and there is nothing for the child to do if it fails.  If you've not forked and you're going to return to other code, then you need to clean up the allocated memory before returning from the function.

Note, too, that the executed program must convert the strings back to integers before processing the result.